# How does this -ve power supply work?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, negative-voltage

[This data sheet](https://static.rapidonline.com/pdf/61-6211_v1.pdf) (linked from the product page of Rapid p/n [61-6211](https://www.rapidonline.com/Catalogue/Product/61-6211)) covers an adapter for LVDS displays, that can provide various different voltages. This includes a 'VGL' signal that is set at -6.8V.

The datasheet helpfully includes a schematic, but having never designed a -ve supply, I'm hoping someone can help me to understand how the part of the circuit that creates this -ve voltage works:
[image: Schematic extract].

The part we're interested in is on the right hand side, but the rest is included for context.
The MIC2289 is a switching regulator; VOut (AVDD) is ~10V.

The zener D2 is rated at 6.8V, so it looks like changing this value changes the -ve supply, but I would really like to know the 'how' and the 'why'?

Comment: It's just a charge pump followed by a zener-regulated emitter follower.

Comment: As it's not drawn conventionally, and I'm not familiar with the concepts, are you possibly able to offer a more verbose description as a full answer? I've gotten my hands on the actual board the schematic describes and have tried replacing D2 with a 6V2 part but don't see 6V2 on the output...